# Dynamically change the URL of a Facebook Send Button

Tags: javascript, facebook, send

I am trying to dynamically change the URL of a Facebook Send button with Javascript, but I have had no success so far.

I have a page set up with a few inputs, and I would like the URL of the send button to take the fields value as parameters before it sends it. The problem is when I add the send button to the page, it generates the iframe code inside and even if I modify the href parameter later on, the iframe still keeps the original link in. I guess the solution would be to refresh the content of the send button somehow or add it after page load, once the fields have been completed, but I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: for instance, I have a name input. If you put Julio in it, the send button should send the URL http://www.myurl?name=Julio

Comment: When the input changes, re-render the send button iframe with the new params then using `FB.XFBML.parse();`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Javascript can't be used to control an iFrame on a different domain than yours. This is due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

What you can do is change the parameters on you send button xfbml tag and then call `FB.XFBML.parse();` so the button uses the new parameters.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me with the URL change. Now my problem is that the Facebook Send button seems to be stripping out the parameters of the URL string... ie: http://www.myurl.com?x=1&y=2 becomes http://www.myurl.com?x=1&fb_source=message...

Comment: I can't see why that is happening. However, if FB will only allow one parameter, use an encoding other than the default one. For instance, you could do `myurl.com?myparams=x_1|y_2`. That would treat `x_1|y_2` as the value of `myparams`, and you would then parse accordingly.

Comment: That solution could work, altough unfortunately I already have a first parameter which is the id of my page, so I can't hack it... I tried adding a # instead of the & though, but FB also gets rid of it.

Comment: Not really, I am developing for a big website already set up in that way, so I can't in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the iFrame version of the like button instead the XFBML version. The like button can be post-loaded into the page after the form submission, via an AJAX call, in which you have passed the data filled up in the form.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like it could work, the problem is that I can't use any server side script files. It has to be done in HTML and JS only, on the same page.